# Best practices for translatable models in Entity Framework Core 2.1+

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, multilingual, efcore

I'm building an Entity Framework Core-backed ASP.NET Core RESTful service and I have entities / models such as Product, Document etc with description in multiple languages.
I want to be able to dynamically query Products with relative Documents by providing their basic information with translated descriptions (based on current UI culture set by headers/cookies etc)

Unfortunately EF Core's `Include` called on navigation properties **can't** be filtered like this:

```
_dbContext.Products
   .Include(p => p.Documents,
          d => d.Language.Equals(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName));
```

I know EF Core 2.1 has global filters now, which can be used to manage soft delete or multi-tenancy etc, but I need per-request filters by language (if needed).

So I'm wondering how do I accomplish such functionality and if there is any best practice for managing translations in EF Core 2.1 in general (e.g. via an [Owned] property, a navigation property with some extension for conditional include etc)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there's no out of the box functionality for your use case.

Note however that you can always do a manual join:

```cs
var result = _dbContext
    .Products
    .Join(
        _dbContext
            .Documents
            .Where(d => d.Language.Equals(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName)),
        product => product.ID,
        document => document.ProductID,
        (product, document) => new {Product = product, Document = document}
    );
```

And use a `GroupBy` or anything else you might need later on

Comment: This is kinda what I thought; if `Include` doesn't do it for you, ratchet down to something a bit more fundamental.